# error in mysql : Invalid use of NULL value

Tags: mysql

as a GUI for MySQL I use `Heidi` I created two simple talbes `work` and `work_info`

There is a query for create `work` table

```
CREATE TABLE `work` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

[image]

and there is for `work_info`

```
CREATE TABLE `work_info` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_work_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `work_id` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `work_name` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `file_name` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_work_info_work` (`ref_work_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_work_info_work` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_work_id`) REFERENCES `gridmanagerdb`.`work` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

[image]

So, `work_info` has a `foreigh_key` to `work`, problem is that I don't like to allow `ref_work_id` to be `null` (I am new to DB) because there is no way that we have `work_info` that doesn't associated to `work`.

When I try to uncheck `Allow NULL` for `ref_work_id`

```
ALTER TABLE `work_info`
CHANGE COLUMN `ref_work_id` `ref_work_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

I got this error

> /* SQL Error (1138): Invalid use of NULL value */

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was there any data in the `work_info` table when you did the alter command which generated this error?

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfe8e977617bcc3867928ee01f19b613 The error means that you have some data in `work_info` whith does not match `NOT NULL` restriction in `ref_work_id`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6cea46ac4d9bd95a2cf14c0fd8be280

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Comment: @Akina oh, it is my mistake (as I told I am new in DB) I really have a data in this table that doesn't match this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your `work_info` table currently has some `NULL` values in the `ref_work_id` column.  By enforcing a `NOT NULL` constraint, you are putting MySQL in a position where your column/table still has `NULL` values, but now it doesn't know what to do with them.  Hence, you get this error.  To confirm this, run the following query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM work_info
WHERE ref_work_id IS NULL;
```

If you get a non zero count from the above query, it would confirm what I am suggesting here.

Comment: oh, it is my mistake (as I told I am new in DB) I really have a data in this table that doesn't match this condition

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko The behavior you get in this situation might be database dependent, and there could be DBs out there which might just assign some default value in place of the `NULL`s.  I prefer the MySQL error, as it gives you a chance to right the problems in your data.